# creating html dropdown menu with labels or helper text inside to show sections

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, xhtml, categories

I m looking to have a html dropdown list created like this:

```
Category1
   Value1
   Value2
Category2
   Value3
   Value4
Category3
   Value5
   Value6
```

and so on..

Where Category1.. Category3 are just labels within the drowpdown list, and are not actual values that can be selected by the user. It is just to bring in that segmentation between categories. The actual values which the user can select are the Value1, Value2,...

I do not know how to specify these categories within the dropdown list. How can i give such helper text within the dropdown?

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an article about this here:  http://www.lost-in-code.com/programming/xhtml/html-option-groupssections/

You have to wrap the sections in an optgroup with the desired label.

Comment: That site gives the code. Exactly what i wanted. I just added an extra line of code to make the default value displayed as blank. That line goes like this:  <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>  Thank You.